# python: casting to upper and finding string

Tags: python

i am getting stuck on this line:

`row[1].upper().find('CELEBREX',1)` (this is returning `-1`)

it seems to not find CELEBREX even though it is there

```
row[1] = 'celebrex, TRAMADOL'
```

am i casting to UPPER incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think "casting" is the right word here.  Python doesn't have type declarations.  You're just calling a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of find() shouldn't be `1`, because it will start search *after* the first character of the string.

```
>>> s = 'celebrex, TRAMADOL'
>>> print s.upper().find('CELEBREX')
0
```

Find() will return 0 because it found the first match at position `0`, the first position in the string. So it's important to note that, as you've already discovered, the if find() doesn't find the string, it will return -1. Return value 0 is actually a match.

Answer (score 2):

`upper()` seems fine, but find doesn't.  You want to find at the start of the string (not offset).

```
row[1].upper().find('CELEBREX')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting search from second letter 1 which is e:

```
row=("",'celebrex, TRAMADOL')
print row[1].upper().find('CELEBREX',1)
print row[1][1:]
"""Output:
-1
elebrex, TRAMADOL
"""
```